# What tense to use in this example?

Tags: tenses, past-tense

I am developing a system for patients that allows them to see their medication history.

There is a function that lists history of all drugs the patients have ever tried. I am trying to figure out what would be the correct tense:

> History of all drugs you have been taking

Does this include the ones in the past (not
being taken anymore)?

> History of all drugs you used to take

Does this include the ones currently being taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most medical charts simply state ***Medication History*** (including all non-prescription medications and supplements).

*Drugs* has a different connotation here, and a drug history is used to separately document alcohol and illicit drug use.

*History of all drugs you have been taking* asks about all drugs being taken over a period of time including now, but not the entire medication history.

*History of all drugs you used to take* does not include now.

You might want something like this, in order to avoid the problems you have asked about: "List all medications you have taken, including those you have discontinued and those you are taking currently."

Comment: Thank you. So there is no tense that could be used for it? What about "All drugs you have taken"?

Comment: You still need to add, *and are taking now* to avoid confusion.

Comment: or use "Current Medication" for those still in effect

Answer (score 0):

'History of all drugs you have been taking', suggests only those of recent date, or associated with a particular condition.

'History of all drugs you used to take' suggests it is not an up-to-date record.

My suggestion, if you want to include everything would be:

'Recorded history of all medication taken'. You may want to footnote this with the warning that the information is limited by the records that exist.